# Are these fairtrade chocolates vegetable-product or do they contain non-veg elements?

Tags: vegetarian-diet, labeling, is-it-vegetarian, dairy-products

[image: front image]
[image: ingredients]
[image: nutrition info]

We eat vegetables and milk.
And we do NOT eat eggs, fish, meat or any animal product.

1. Are these two chocolates made up of milk + vegetables or do they contain any non-veg elements as stated above?

I've attached three photos of the same two chocolates. Struggling to identify for these fin Carre chocolates received from Spain. And the language on the chocolate wrapper seems to be in Spanish (which I don't know), and I don't see that green color dot or red color dot inside the square of the same color - to indicate veg or non-veg product that we can generally see on product wrappers in India.

2. In my attempt to convert the ingredients to English with help of google translator, I came to know it contains lecithins and gluten. Are they vegetable product?

Comment: milk is an animal product

Comment: you're already using google for translation ... ask it about gluten and lecithin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### These chocolate bars are not solely made of vegetable products.

- Sugar
- Almonds
- Cacao butter
- **Fat-free milk powder** *
- Cacao paste
- **Whey powder** *
- Concentrated butter
- Hazelnut paste
- Emulsifier: Sunflower lecithin
- Vanilla Extract
- Can contain traces of other nuts, soy, peanuts or gluten.

##### * The ingredients in bold contain milk and thus are of animal origin.

The contained lecithin is of vegetable origin (sunflower). Gluten is only listed as a possible allergen, but gluten is of vegetable origin anyway (cereal).